# How to distinguish between an event triggered by a mouse action VS an event triggered by EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a listener associated to a specific type of action performed on a specific component in EXTJS. In other words I want to know when the user performed some particular action on a component.

My problem is that this listener is also triggered on refresh (assume we cannot avoid this). Is there any way to filter these events, i.e. listen only to those triggered by the user?

Thank you for your time

Comment: The question is pretty vague. Provide a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to prevent an event from firing, say *refresh* event on a list, you can do something like this

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    itemId: 'altList',
    listeners: {
        refresh: {
            order: 'before',
            fn: function(list, eOpts) {
                if(//something)
                    return false;          //Returning false will cancel the action 
                else
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can do this for any preventable event on any component.

Hope this helps!